# Edit HTML template on Blogger to add GitHub Fork Me ribbon

Tags: blogger, html, blogger-templates

I am trying to modify my active Blogger.com template like this:

[image: edit HTML button]

I want to add a [GitHub "Fork Me" ribbon](https://github.com/blog/273-github-ribbons) to my template page and have tried pasting in the templates in the head tag and in the body tag. In both cases I get error messages like this from the blogger site:

> We're sorry, but we were unable to complete your request.
>
> When reporting this error to Blogger Support or on the Blogger Help Group, please:
>
> Describe what you were doing when you got this error.
>
> Provide the following error code
>
> bX-mpatqh
>
> This information will help us track down your specific problem and fix it! We apologize for the inconvenience.

Is it possible to add such a snippet of code to a Blogger site by editing the template HTML? Where is the correct place to paste in the code snippet?

I tried a suggested approach to add the code in a widget on the page, unfortunately the result was not 100%. The ribbon shows up on top of the post archives, whereas I would like to show it further out, see below:

here how I modified the layout:

[image: blogLayout]

and here the result:

[image: blogresult]

I think it may be possible to achieve the desired result with templates modifications, but it doesn't look like an easy task (to me) to modify the template.

The template that I use is based on the "Simple" one, but it still has a lot of code in it when you view the HTML.

Comment: Add an HTML widget with the code.

Answer (score 3):

The code the ribbon site provides lacks a `</img>` close tag. add it before `</a>` should make it display on your blogger.

The full code:
`<a href="https://github.com"><img style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; border: 0;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/github/ribbons/forkme_left_red_aa0000.png" alt="Fork me on GitHub"></img></a>`

Add it before the `</body>` should do the job. It works for [my blogger](http://ynotserious.blogspot.com/).

[image]